# How can I close the Netrw buffer?

Tags: netrw

How can I close the Netrw buffer?

I tried both :bd and :bw and neither work.

Comment: It's in its own window/pane? `:close`?

Answer (score 13):

The `autocmd FileType netrw setl bufhidden=wipe` still leaves one buffer open. I found this solution, which closes it after opening the file:

`let g:netrw_fastbrowse = 0`

over at the discussion on https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/13

Comment: Using both (autocmd and fastbrow) worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I've had this problem, when using Vinegar to make netrw easier to use.  I found a site that offers one solution [here](https://codeyarns.com/2015/02/02/cannot-close-buffer-of-netrw-in-vim/), and [more solutions here.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/13)

The solution that worked for me, was to add this to my `.vimrc`:

```bash
autocmd FileType netrw setl bufhidden=wipe
```

For the sake of completeness, other solutions:

**@serebrov** on Github:

```bash
function! QuitNetrw()
  for i in range(1, bufnr($))
    if buflisted(i)
      if getbufvar(i, '&filetype') == "netrw"
        silent exe 'bwipeout ' . i
      endif
    endif
  endfor
endfunction

autocmd MyAutoCmd VimLeavePre *  call QuitNetrw()
```

**@slashfoo** on Github:

```bash
" Remove 'set hidden'
set nohidden

augroup netrw_buf_hidden_fix
    autocmd!

    " Set all non-netrw buffers to bufhidden=hide
    autocmd BufWinEnter *
                \  if &ft != 'netrw'
                \|     set bufhidden=hide
                \| endif

augroup end
```

The first solution was posted by **@tpope**, also on github.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all kind of solutions from here and some other places, none worked as expected, respectively I didn't like the implementation much (e.g. the one using `augroup netrw_buf_hidden_fix`), so I ended up with this for closing `netrw` using `Esc` or `q`

```
autocmd FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer><silent> <Esc> :call <SID>CloseNetrw()<CR>
autocmd FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer><silent> q     :call <SID>CloseNetrw()<CR>
...
function! s:CloseNetrw() abort
  for bufn in range(1, bufnr('$'))
    if bufexists(bufn) && getbufvar(bufn, '&filetype') ==# 'netrw'
      silent! execute 'bwipeout ' . bufn
      if getline(2) =~# '^" Netrw '
        silent! bwipeout
      endif
      return
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

Please note, always place `autocmd` inside a group.

Answer (score -3):

typing `q` while in the buffer closes mine.